# breakdown of a install.rb file, please help me understand this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking at the install.rb file of RoR open source project:

```
version = ARGV.pop

%w( core api auth dash promotions sample ).each do |framework|
  puts "Installing #{framework}..."
  `cd #{framework} && gem build spree_#{framework}.gemspec && gem install spree_#{framework}-#{version}.gem --no-ri --no-rdoc && rm spree_#{framework}-#{version}.gem`
end

puts "Installing Spree..."
`gem build spree.gemspec`
`gem install spree-#{version}.gem --no-ri --no-rdoc `
`rm spree-#{version}.gem
```

the lines i'm interested in at the moment are:

gem build spree_core.gemspec && gem install spree_core-xxxx.gem

the core.gemspec looks like:

```
version = File.read(File.expand_path("../../SPREE_VERSION", __FILE__)).strip

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.platform    = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.name        = 'spree_core'
  s.version     = version
  s.summary     = 'Core e-commerce functionality for the Spree project.'
  s.description = 'Required dependancy for Spree'

  s.required_ruby_version = '>= 1.8.7'
  s.author      = 'Sean Schofield'
  s.email       = 'sean@railsdog.com'
  s.homepage    = 'http://spreecommerce.com'
  s.rubyforge_project = 'spree_core'

  s.files        = Dir['LICENSE', 'README.md', 'app/**/*', 'config/**/*', 'lib/**/*']
  s.require_path = 'lib'
  s.requirements << 'none'

  s.add_dependency('acts_as_list', '>= 0.1.2')
  s.add_dependency('rd_awesome_nested_set', '>= 1.4.4')
  s.add_dependency('rd_unobtrusive_date_picker', '>= 0.1.0')

  s.add_dependency('highline', '>= 1.5.1')
  #s.add_dependency('less', '>= 1.2.20')
  s.add_dependency('stringex', '>= 1.0.3')
  s.add_dependency('state_machine', '>= 0.9.4')
  s.add_dependency('faker', '>= 0.3.1')
  s.add_dependency('paperclip', '>= 2.3.1.1')
  s.add_dependency('rd_resource_controller')
  s.add_dependency('rd_searchlogic', '>= 3.0.0.rc3')
  s.add_dependency('activemerchant', '>= 1.7.1')
  s.add_dependency('will_paginate', '>= 3.0.pre')
end
```

What is this doing?
It seems to generate a file b/c there is a call to rm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the gem is installed with the

```
gem install
```

command you no longer need the .gem file. It's just a left-over at this point as all the contents of the package have been placed in the file system. There's no need to keep it around so the .gem file is deleted; it's done its job to get all the files to you in a one-file bundle

Comment: so the add_depedancy will download the file?

Comment: that's one of the nice parts about gems, gem will download dependencies if it can find them.

Answer (score 0):

It generates a gem-file, installs it and removes it afterwards?